# getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tabTag) return NULL

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

I have 2 tabs with tagID "tag01" and "tag02". I have explicitly set
the focus to first tab by calling tabHost.setCurrentTab(0)

When i call `getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("tag01")` i get the
object of activity but when i call

```
getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("tag02") then i get NULL.
//Log.i("tab status: ", getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("tag02")+""); prints null
//Log.i("tab status: ", getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("tag01")+""); prints com.test.TestActivity@437c06c8
```

Now when i again run my app and this time click second tab and then
`getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("tag02")` gives object
(toString() in logcat).
So after checking it again and again i found that "only activity in
first tab( that i had set focus explicitly by
`tabHost.setCurrentTab(0)`) returns non-null" and other tabs return null
unless u don't click those tab.
When i click all tabs i.e atleast i go through all tabs by clicking
them then `getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(anyTag)` returns
object(i am tracing toString()) . How to access activity from other
tabs without clicking other tabs because user won't know that he/she
has to click tabs.
Please give some suggestions. Because i have to access activity in
tabs in my app.
I hope you understood my problem.

thanks

Comment: Why do you use tabs if you don't want them to be clicked? Why not use just one activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity is not created!

if you have `n` tabs You could do this in your onCreate():

```
for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--)
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(i);
```

In this way, the tab displayed is the first tab (with index 0) and `getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(anyTag)` will return non-null

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Just a minor modification in above code 
`for(int i=list.size()-1;i>0;i--)
     tabHost.setCurrentTab(i);`
i-- instead of i++ :D
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

i could able to get the activity instance with out running the for loop by setting the CurrentTab property value before calling getactivity function.

i.e

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(i); //i index of anytab activity
getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(anyTag);
```